# Difference between Fetch Requests (model templates) and Fetched Properties in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

What's the difference between them? Both need predicate. I've used them both but I can't understand the difference. Thanks! (I think it doesn't matter, but I'm working in iOS, Xcode 4 last version).

Answer (score 3):

A fetched property is kind of a relationship. It's not a direct, two-way relationship, it's a one-way relationship. So only one one object knows about the relationship. The fetched property is (normally) described by a predicate and uses a fetch request to retrieve the objects.

A fetch request retrieves objects from core-data. The actual instances of an entity. It doesn't need a predicate if you don't need to filter the objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. same:all cached query method;
2. difference:

   - Fetch Requests-->really Fetch Requests;just fetch something from a single table
   - Fetched Properties --> fetch something from different table based on data from this table;like use :select from table2 where id = thisrow.id